# scale an object based on it's velocity

Tags: geometry-nodes

is it possible to drive an objects scale based on how fast it's moving? I'd settle for scaling the points of the object through something like geo nodes? I had a quick look in geo nodes but, the solution didn't jump out at me so I thought I'd ask if this is possible in Blender before investing too much time to this.
Many thanks

Comment: Not experienced enough with it to post an answer, but I think it should be possible with the new (very alpha) Simulation branch. You could capture and store the Self Object's position info and compare it to the previous frame's data, then use that to scale. For a beginner-level demonstration of it: https://youtu.be/9AROoKXxpS0?t=338

Comment: What's your setup, how do you define the movement from which you want to get the velocity? Do you animate the object using keyframes, or a driver, or physics...? Please read this post for an advice how to write a good question: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2620/could-we-brush-up-the-help-center-please

Comment: The object in question is inheriting it's animation from it's parent, which is in turn driven by a follow path constraint. Although I would like a system that works with motion drive by key frame animation. As thatt happens in some shots